# avro schema must fill either fullname or SSN

Tags: avro

So, I have customer data which will have `fullname`, `address`, `SSN`, `DOB`, etc.

So, the requirement is if `firstname` is empty, then `SSN` must be filled and vice versa. we MUST allow customer to omit at most one of them.

By default, fields in avro are mandatory. if we want to make it optional, we need to use union. but is this requirement possible in avro schema with unions? is there any syntax or way to declare this requirement in AVDL?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Avro doesn't support this use case out of the box. To make it work, you'd probably need a schema like this:

```
{
    "type": "record",
    "name": "Person",
    "fields": [
        {"type": "string", "name": "required_ssn_or_firstname"},
        {"type": "string", "name": "optional_ssn_or_firstname"},
        {"type": "enum", "name": "ssn_or_firstname", "symbols": ["SSN", "FIRSTNAME"]},
        ...
    ]
}
```

Then, in your application, you would have to have some logic for the different cases:

Case 1: User provides firstname but not SSN
Avro Record:

```
{
    "required_ssn_or_firstname": "Alice"
    "optional_ssn_or_firstname": ""
    "ssn_or_firstname": "FIRSTNAME"
    ...
}
```

Case 2: User provides SSN but not firstname
Avro Record:

```
{
    "required_ssn_or_firstname": "111223344"
    "optional_ssn_or_firstname": ""
    "ssn_or_firstname": "SSN"
    ...
}
```

Case 3: User provides both SSN and firstname
Avro Record:

```
{
    "required_ssn_or_firstname": "Bob"
    "optional_ssn_or_firstname": "999887766"
    "ssn_or_firstname": "FIRSTNAME" 
    ...
}
```

Comment: But if we need to involve application, then I'm not sure we need schema to enforce this. the validation will be done by application essentially? am I missing something?

Comment: Good point. Yeah, it probably doesn't make sense to complicate the schema if you have to do the validation in the app.